# Dividing a link in two lines

Tags: html, html-table, hyperlink, eclipselink, divide

How can I divide a link into two lines?!

Suppose I want to see "www.google.com" in two lines because the link I am fetching from database with ${xyz}, it's entering into the next column.
So If I can divide that link in two parts somehow, maybe it will stay inside it's respective column.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!!! It worked like a charm.